# Specification mandate value for attribute required

Tags: javascript, django, dojo

I was working with Django/Dojo project. As suddenly I cannot modify HTML file. When I trie to edit it, my browser shows this message:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 11 at column 79: Specification mandate value for attribute required
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

The line that causing the problem is:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox">
```

I don't understand what is causing this.

Is this Dojo problem, or Dreamweaver's or Google Chrome's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested I found a solution. For some reason once I would save and upload file to the server (using Dreamweaver) it would change:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required="true">
```

into

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" required>
```

And this caused a problem. Very very weird.. I guess it is DW's fault.